How can I export all the photos and videos from the iPhone to my flash drive?
I have a flash drive connected to my iphone via cable. How can I export all the photos and videos from the iPhone to my flash drive?
I found support.apple.com:

Export photos and videos to an external storage device
You can export photos and videos you took on your iPhone directly to an external drive, a memory card, or other storage device.
Note: For photos and videos that have been edited, the unmodified original version will be exported.

Connect your iPhone to the storage device using the Lightning or USB-C connector, or connect the device directly to your iPhone.

Open the Photos app, then select the photos and videos you want to export.

Tap , then tap Export Unmodified Original.

Tap your storage device (below Locations), then tap Save.



but it requires me to manually select all the photos and videos, which is time consuming when having many thousands of pictures and videos, even after zooming out and selecting rows by scrolling. Is there a faster way? I feel I'm missing something eg the ability to simply select an entire album at once.

Albums have "select all" feature, but the "all photos" view does not. Guess you have to enter selection mode, swipe right on the first photo and drag down to bottom and hold there until it reaches the end...
